# How the number of pre-smoothing and post-smoothing steps affect the asymtotic convergence rate of geometrical Multigrid?

Tags: iterative-method, convergence, multigrid, smoothing

Does the convergence rate of multigrid depend on the total number of smoothing steps or on the number of pre and post smoothing steps seperately?

Answer (score 3):

Separately, but it does depend. Not very strongly, however: A very large number of pre- and post-smoothing steps only improves the convergence rate a little bit over a large number of steps. The difference is most between using one, two, or three pre- and post-smoothing steps.

And you need both pre- and post-smoothing steps. You cannot compensate for no pre-smoothing steps by using more post-smoothing steps.

Comment: In this case what happened?If for example use (1,1) or (0,2) or (2,0) smoothing steps for example.Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not an expert in MG behavior. I suspect that for the (0,2) and (2,0) case, you can't prove convergence, but it might converge (slowly) anyway in practice.

Comment: I did find an excellent reference: The book of Elman, Silvester, and Wathen on "Finite elements and fast solvers" has exactly the kind of table you are look for on p. 105. You really do need *both* pre- and post-smoothing to get mesh-independent convergence rates.

Comment: Is this book online?I couldn't find any reference.Can you send me a link or something?Thank you!

Comment: I don't know. I happen to have the book.

Comment: Ok.If you can post the answer it will be great!Anyway thank you for your time!

Comment: In short, if you have 2 pre- and zero post-smoothing steps, or if you have 0 pre- and 2 post-smoothing steps, then the number of iterations you need to solve the linear system grows with the refinement level. In other words, without *both* pre- and post-smoothing, the multigrid method is not mesh independent.